# Accessing Map of Map by a valid key gives NPE

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a map:

```java
Map<Long, Map<Integer, Integer>> employeeYearWiseLeaveAppCount=new HashMap<>();
```

this map is filled with values in some other place. Now, I need to access the inner map like this:

```java
for (AnnualLeaveBalance balance: annualLeaveBalanceList) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> yearToCountMap = employeeYearWiseLeaveAppCount.get(
        balance.getEmployeeId()
    );
    int year = Integer.valueOf(balance.getYear());
    int takenLeave = yearToCountMap.get(year); //year is valid value. NPE here!
}
```

The key I am passing to this map  `employeeYearWiseLeaveAppCount.get(balance.getEmployeeId());` does exist in the map with valid value but `yearToCountMap` is showing as null.
Please, help what is wrong here?

Comment: Try `employeeYearWiseLeaveAppCount.get(Long.valueOf(balance.getEmployeeId())); `

Comment: The line `int year= Integer.valueOf(balance.getYear());` makes no sense. `valueOf` will convert an `int` to an `Integer`, which you implicitly convert to an `int` when assigning to `year`. Besides that, you have to check whether `yearToCountMap` or the result of `yearToCountMap.get(year)` was `null`. Both would result in an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of null checks are needed to prevent NPE, however in both cases this can be resolved with the help of [`Map::getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)) method.

Also, the type and assignment to `year` should be simplified.  `Integer.valueOf` is needed only if `balance.getYear()` returns a string value, otherwise it would be ok to have it as `Integer year = balance.getYear();`

```java
for (AnnualLeaveBalance balance: annualLeaveBalanceList) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> yearToCountMap = employeeYearWiseLeaveAppCount.getOrDefault(
        balance.getEmployeeId(), Collections.emptyMap()
    ); // empty map is returned if no yearToCount map is found for a user

    Integer year = balance.getYear();
    int takenLeave = yearToCountMap.getOrDefault(year, 0); // no leave taken
}
```